# Jquery Display JSON data corresponding to multiple options selected

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm developing a widget that request fares.json via AJAX and populates select options with live data. End users should be able to see the fare total update when they use the widget controls.

JSON Data:

```
{
"info": {
    "anytime": "Valid anytime",
    "weekday": "Valid Monday through Friday, 4:00 a.m. - 7:00 p.m. On trains arriving or departing 30th Street Station, Suburban and Jefferson Station",
    "evening_weekend": "Valid weekdays after 7:00 p.m.; all day Saturday, Sunday and major holidays. On trains arriving or departing 30th Street Station, Suburban and Jefferson Station",
    "advance_purchase": "Tickets available for purchase at all SEPTA offices.",
    "onboard_purchase": "Tickets available for purchase from a train conductor aboard SEPTA regional rail trains."
},
"zones": [{
    "name": "CCP/Zone 1",
    "zone": 1,
    "fares": [{
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 4.75
    }, {
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 6.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 3.75
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 5.00
    }, {
        "type": "anytime",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 10,
        "price": 38.00
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Zone 2",
    "zone": 2,
    "fares": [{
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 4.75
    }, {
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 6.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 3.75
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 5.00
    }, {
        "type": "anytime",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 10,
        "price": 45.00
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Zone 3",
    "zone": 3,
    "fares": [{
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 5.75
    }, {
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 7.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 5.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 7.00
    }, {
        "type": "anytime",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 10,
        "price": 54.50
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Zone 4",
    "zone": 4,
    "fares": [{
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 6.50
    }, {
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 8.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 5.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 7.00
    }, {
        "type": "anytime",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 10,
        "price": 62.50
    }]
}, {
    "name": "NJ",
    "zone": 5,
    "fares": [{
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 9.00
    }, {
        "type": "weekday",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 10.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 9.00
    }, {
        "type": "evening_weekend",
        "purchase": "onboard_purchase",
        "trips": 1,
        "price": 10.00
    }, {
        "type": "anytime",
        "purchase": "advance_purchase",
        "trips": 10,
        "price": 80.00
    }]
}]}
```

My HTML has id's for each place where data should populate.

HTML:

```
<select id="zone"></select><select id="time"></select>
<form id="radio" class="widget-container--radio">
    <input type="radio" name="purchase" value="advance_purchase"> Station Kiosk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="purchase" value="onboard_purchase"> Onboard<br>
</form>
<form><input type="number" name="firstname" class="widget-container--quantity"><br></form>
<div id="fare-total" class="widget-container--fare"></div>
```

And I wrote a bit of jQuery to get the JSON data and output options. The desired affect is when a option is selected (name, type, purchase, and trip) the fare total will display below in #fare-total. How do I achieve this?

Jquery:

```
var $zone = $('#zone');
var $time = $('#time');
var $radio = $('#radio');
var $fareTotal = $('#fare-total');
$.getJSON('fares.json', function(data) {
  $zone.html('');
  $time.html('');
  $radio.html('');
  $fareTotal.html('');
  for (i = 0; i < data['zones'].length; i++) {
    $zone.append('<option class="' + data['zones'][i]['name'] + '">' + data['zones'][i]['name'] + '</option>');
    $time.append('<option>' + data['zones'][i]['fares'][i]['type'] + '</option>');
    $fareTotal.append('<h2 class="">$' + data['zones'][i]['fares'][i]['price'] + '</h2>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Put the fare data in a global variable. Then when the user selects an option, search for the the fare associated with that option, get its price, and put it into the total DIV.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure how to write that, especially since it needs to be dependent on the other options being selected. Could you write out an example?

Comment: Why are you using the same index for the `zones` array and the `fares` array inside it? It looks like you need cascading menus: when the user selects a different zone, you need to change the fares menu to have the fares for that zone.

Comment: @Barmar that is correct. When a different zone and time option is selected, a single fare total should display.

Answer (score 0):

If the fare data is static, I would advise moving it to a local source or global variable as was suggested by @Barmar.

If the fares change a lot, then AJAX is a better way to go. Here are some suggestions.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vsjn63vy/

**Suggested JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var $zone = $('#zone');
  var $time = $('#time');
  var $radio = $('#radio');
  var $fareTotal = $('#fare-total');
  $.getJSON('fares.json', function(data) {
      $zone.html('');
      $time.html('');
      $radio.html('');
      $fareTotal.html('');
      $.each(data.zones, function(i, zone) {
        $zone.append($("<option>", {
          class: zone.name
        }).html(zone.name));
        $time.append($("<option>").html(zone.fares[i].type));
        $fareTotal.append($("<h2>").html(zone.fares[i].price));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this out. However it should only show one fare total, when you select the zone and time options.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. When a zone and time option is selected, only the fare total for that time option should display.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the JSON, you should just fill in the zone menu, because the time options depend on which zone you've selected.

The radio button options don't come from the JSON, so you shouldn't clear that DIV, just uncheck the buttons so the user has to choose them again.

After the user selects a zone, you then fill in the time menu. And once they select a time and one of the radio buttons, you can then display the cost.

```js
var $zone = $('#zone');
var $time = $('#time');
var $radio = $('#radio').find(":radio");
var $fareTotal = $('#fare-total');
var fare_data = null;
$.getJSON('fares.json', function(data) {
  fare_data = data;
  $zone.html('<option value="">Select a zone</option>');
  $time.html('<option value="">Zone must be selected first</option>');
  $radio.prop('checked', false); // uncheck all the boxes
  $fareTotal.html('');
  $.each(data.zones, function() {
    $zone.append($('<option>', {
      value: this.zone,
      text: this.name
    }));
  });
});

$zone.change(function() {
  var zone = this.value;
  $fareTotal.empty();
  $radio.prop('checked', false); // uncheck all the boxes
  if (zone == '') {
    $time.html('<option value="">Zone must be selected first</option>');
    return;
  }
  $time.html('<option value="">Select a time</option>');
  $.each(fare_data.zones, function() {
    if (this.zone == zone) {
      var fares_appended = {};
      $.each(this.fares, function() {
        if (!fares_appended[this.type]) {
          $time.append($('<option>', {
            value: this.type,
            text: fare_data.info[this.type]
          }));
          fares_appended[this.type] = true;
        }
        return false; // break the $.each loop
      });
    }
  });
});

function calc_price() {
  var zone = $zone.val();
  var type = $time.val();
  var purchase = $radio.find(":radio:checked").val();
  $fareTotal.empty();
  if (zone && time && purchase) {
    $.each(fare_data.zones, function() {
      if (this.zone == zone) {
        $.each(this.fares, function() {
          if (this.type == type && this.purchase = purchase) {
            $fareTotal.append($('<h2>', {
              text: '$' + this.price
            }));
            return false;
          }
        });
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}

$time.change(calc_price);
$radio.change(calc_price);
```

Comment: Thank you @barmar, that worked for what I'm trying to do.